# Permissions to access an encrypted external HDD

Tags: permissions, encryption, external-hdd, ext4

I have an external HDD which has an encrypted ext4 filesystem.

When I plug it into one of my laptops and provide the encryption password, I get this popup box saying:

> You do not have permissions necessary to view the contents of LABEL

When I connect it to my other laptop things are fine and I can access the drive contents.

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: If you try and access it as root, can you do it? If so, maybe is just a permission issue. Cheers

Comment: Does your other laptop has Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, both laptops are on Ubuntu 12.04 and i am able to access the HDD as root. I understand it is a permission problem -- how can I setup things such that I can access the HDD from both laptops?